# FileUpload on listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, listview, file-upload

I have ListView that display info from XML and to save to server from FileUpload that are on this ListView. I dont have problem to write to the XML, the problem is on save the FileUpload to folder.

1. I belive that i have mistake that i not seperate the listview to itemtemplate and insertemplate and edit...It must to? because the title going to correct place on XML, and even file name. but the file not saved to the folder.
2. For most tests i did - nothing happent after click on "update" BTN. when i add the int "i" to the items[i] somtimes it just update the xml without saving the file, and sometimes i get error of "out of index".

What is wrong?

## ASPX code

```
<h2><asp:Label ID="LBL_number" runat="server" Text='<%#XPath("id") %>'></asp:Label></h2>
<h2>Small Image</h2> <asp:Image Width="100"  CssClass="ltr" runat="server" ID="TB_small" ImageUrl='<%# XPath("small_image_url") %>'></asp:Image><asp:FileUpload ID="FU_small" runat="server" />
<br /><br /><br />
<h2>Big Image</h2> <asp:Image Width="300" CssClass="ltr" runat="server" ID="TB_big" ImageUrl='<%#XPath("big_image_url") %>'></asp:Image><asp:FileUpload ID="FU_big" runat="server" />
<br /><br />
<h2>Title</h2> <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TB_title" Text='<%#XPath("title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<br /><br /><br />
<asp:Button CssClass="btn" ID="Button1" CommandArgument='<%#XPath("id") %>' runat="server"  OnClick="update"  Text="Update" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" CssClass="btn" CommandArgument='<%#XPath("id") %>' runat="server" CommandName="del"  OnClick="del" Text="מחק" />
<br /><br />
<br /><br />
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XDS_data" runat="server" 
  DataFile="~/App_Data/AM_data.xml" XPath="/Data/datas/data">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

## C# Example only with the small file upload.

```
protected void update(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));
    Button myButton = (Button)sender;
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(myButton.CommandArgument.ToString());
    var FU_small1 = (FileUpload)myButton.FindControl("FU_small");
    string extenstion_small = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FU_small1.FileName);
    filename_small = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    FileUpload fu2 = LV_data.Items[i].FindControl("FU_small") as FileUpload;
    if (fu2.HasFile == true)
     {
        fu2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/imgs/data/big" + filename_small.ToString() +  extenstion_small.ToString()));    
     }

        var TB_title = (TextBox)myButton.FindControl("TB_title");
        string myString3 = TB_title.Text;

        XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("Data/datas/data[id='" + i + "']");
        el.SelectSingleNode("small_image_url").InnerText = "~/imgs/data" + filename_small + extenstion_small;
        el.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText = myString3;
        el.SelectSingleNode("big_image_url").InnerText = "~/imgs/data" + filename_big + extenstion_big;

        doc.Save(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));

        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, "foreach" solved it

```
protected void update(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get xml file 
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));
    //Set button for index it later by CommandArgument
    Button myButton = (Button)sender;


    foreach (ListViewItem item in LV_data.Items)
    {
        //Findcontrol of 2 fileupload on listview
        FileUpload FU_small1 = (FileUpload)item.FindControl("FU_small1");
        FileUpload FU_big1 = (FileUpload)item.FindControl("FU_big1");

        //Check if are has file.
        if (FU_small1.HasFile && FU_big1.HasFile)
        {
            //Get extension and genereate random filenames (for avoid ovveride)
            FileInfo small_info = new FileInfo(FU_small1.FileName);
            FileInfo big_info = new FileInfo(FU_big1.FileName);
            string ext_small = small_info.Extension;
            string ext_big = big_info.Extension;
            string filename_small = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string filename_big = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            //Set i value by button CommandArgument (look on aspx on question)
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(myButton.CommandArgument.ToString());

            //Get title from TextBox and set string from it
            TextBox TB_title = myButton.FindControl("TB_title") as TextBox;
            string myString3 = TB_title != null ? TB_title.Text : string.Empty;

            //Save the files from the fileuploads we found, and write it on xml
            FU_small1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "imgs/data/thumbs/" + filename_small + ext_small));
            FU_big1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "imgs/data/big/" + filename_big + ext_big));
            XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("Data/datas/data[id='" + i + "']");
            el.SelectSingleNode("small_image_url").InnerText = "~/imgs/data/thumbs/" + filename_small  + ext_small;
            el.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText = myString3;
            el.SelectSingleNode("big_image_url").InnerText = "~/imgs/data/big/" + filename_big + ext_big;

            doc.Save(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));
        }
    }

    // Refresh the page
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your `update` method:

1. You need to find control inside container, not inside button. **Wrong approach : ** `var TB_title = (TextBox)myButton.FindControl("TB_title");`
2. There's no guarantee that `id` will match ListView's item index. **Wrong approach : **  `FileUpload fu2 = LV_data.Items[i].FindControl("FU_small") as FileUpload;`

etc.

I would suggest to change the method to this:

```
protected void update(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));
    Button myButton = (Button)sender;
    ListViewItem lvwItem = (ListViewItem)myButton.NamingContainer;

    FileUpload FU_small1 = myButton.FindControl("FU_small") as FileUpload;

    if (FU_small1 != null && int.TryParse(myButton.CommandArgument, out index))
    {
        string extenstion_small = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FU_small1.FileName);
        filename_small = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        TextBox TB_title =  myButton.FindControl("TB_title") as TextBox;
        string myString3 = TB_title!= null ? TB_title.Text : string.Empty;

        if (FU_small1.HasFile == true)
        {
            FU_small1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/imgs/data/small/" + filename_small + extenstion_small));
        }
        XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("Data/datas/data[id='" + index + "']");
        el.SelectSingleNode("small_image_url").InnerText = "~/imgs/data/small/" + filename_small + extenstion_small;
        el.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText = myString3;
        el.SelectSingleNode("big_image_url").InnerText = "~/imgs/data/big/" + filename_big + extenstion_big;

        doc.Save(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/AM_data.xml"));
    }

    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

And [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0R1VEQkx0Q2ptUHM/edit?usp=sharing)'s a test project I have used to test this.

Comment: @afzaluhlh wow, thank you for your big efforts. I tried it, and again- its save good to xml, but it seems like it not get the fileupload file. weird, i belive that you tested it and it work for you... i did copy-paste .. i will keep trying.